# Step on range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make this grafic work, but I'm some kind of a new in this whole thing so I have a few things that I can't get to work.

As you can see on the fiddle, my inputs[type=range] are taking values between 0 and 5,000,000. Now, I've managed to modify the steps so between 0 and 150,000 - step=10,000. Between 200,000 and 1,000,000 - step=100,000 and then the step is 500,000. 
But my problem is that it's very hard to drag the thumb to a small value. So, it's easy to select 2,000,000 for example, but very hard to select 20,000.

It's there a solution so the SLIDER's range/segment/section to be wider from 0 to 1,000,000 and less wider from 1m to 5m ?

These is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/4/

And how i've done my steps:

```
$(function() {

  $('#flying2').on("input change", function() {

    var
      element = $('#flying2'),
      value = element.val(),
      step;

    if (value < 150000) {

      step = 10000;
    }else if (value < 250000) {

      step = 50000;

    }else if(value < 500000) {
      step = 100000;

    }else if(value < 500000) {
      step = 100000;

    }     else if(value > 1000000) {
      step = 500000;
    }



    element.attr('step', step);
  });
});
```

If you can help me it will be much appreciated ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself the range element is linear. However with JS you can interpret its value and scale the result. Let's say we go from 1-11 in steps of 0.5. From 1-8 you take 1.000.000 * (value/8), and above 8 you take 1.000.000 + (1.000.000 * (value-7))

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="11" step="0.5" onchange="scaleValue(this);" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function scaleValue(e) {
  if (e.value <= 8) {
    output.value = 1000000 * (e.value / 8);
  } else {
    output.value = 1000000 + (1000000 * (e.value - 7));
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9wpbufwn/)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641373/html5-input-type-range-non-linear-sequence) has a few ideas on how to get a non-linear range on an HTML5 slider.